# Android Notification Sound to Silent

Tags: android, notifications

I have a custom `notification` that I built, every time it pops up it sends a `notification sound`. I want this to be `silent` and not make any sound. I have trying using everything below but nothing seems to work. Everything seems to be deprecated and `setPriority()` is not an option. Looking for solution on how to get the `notification` sound to be silent, any help? My code is below.

***Tried using a combination of all below:***

```
    status.sound = null;
    status.vibrate = null;
    status.defaults &= ~DEFAULT_SOUND;
    status.defaults &= ~DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    status.vibrate = new long[] { -1 };
    status.priority = -2
```

**My Code**

```
    Notification status = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_1_ID).build();
    status.contentView = views;
    status.bigContentView = bigViews;
    status.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    status.icon = R.drawable.ic_music_note;
    status.contentIntent = pendingIntent;
    status.priority = -2;
    startForeground(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE, status);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To mute notification sounds in API 26, use the `IMPORTANCE_LOW` channel, which doesn't contain any sound. Example:

```
 int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
```

Also, make sure to clear app data or reinstall the app in order to have this change take effect in notification channel after changing the importance.

Reference Documentation: [Migrating MediaStyle Notifications to Support Android O](https://medium.com/google-developers/migrating-mediastyle-notifications-to-support-android-o-29c7edeca9b7)

Comment: where would I add this into?

Comment: was able to fix it. I had to create a new channel and make the importance low.